# Intro Slider to be the first activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-fragmentactivity

Help me arrange the Android Manifest properly so that my app can initiate with an intro slider instead of going straight to the main activity.

My current Android Manifest code is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="za.co.danchokoe.diskiquiz">

      <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
           <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>

          <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity" />
           <activity android:name=".ResultPlayAgain" />
           <activity android:name=".ResultWon" />
           <activity android:name=".timeup"></activity>
       </application>
</manifest>
```

I have the code behind for my Introslider as a WelcomeActivity.java and the layout is named activity_welcome.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the .MainActivity to .WelcomeActivity like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="za.co.danchokoe.diskiquiz">

  <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

      <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
       <activity android:name=".ResultPlayAgain" />
       <activity android:name=".ResultWon" />
       <activity android:name=".timeup"></activity>
   </application>
```

With this modification if you start your app the first activity will be your WelcomeActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Remove intent filter code from your main activity and Use that intent filter code inside your Welcome Activity in manifest as

```
       <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intros are supposed to run for the first time only, not on every launch and as I'm assuming you want this so for that here's what you can do as I'm using this and it works fine:

Paste the following code in your launcher activity's `onCreate` (MainActivity in your case), try to paste it just after `setContentView`

```
        Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
        if (isFirstRun) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();
```

This will check for the first run and if it'll be the first run then it will show the intro activity else it will continue showing the MainActivity.
And also, change nothing in your AndroidManifest.XML.